# Unable to create RDS DBParameterGroup using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create an Amazon RDS `DBParameterGroup` group using CloudFormation. It is not getting created and I am also not seeing any errors. Appreciate any help.

```
rdsDBParameterGroup:
   Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
   Properties:
     Description: Database Parameter Group
     Family: postgres11
     Parameters:
       shared_preload_libraries: auto_explain,pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan,pgaudit
```

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that there are no errors but something isn't being created. Once the stack has been created, if you go to the Resources tab in CloudFormation, it should show every resource in the stack, with a link to them or at least a name for each created resource). Does the DB Parameter Group appear in your Resources tab?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Appreciate your help. If I remove the Parameters: line the dbparameter group is getting created. Can you please try on your side if gets created in your account with the Parameters:  Thanks !

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: it is working fine now. ` rdsDBParameterGroup:
       Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
       Properties:
         Description: Database Parameter Group
         Family: postgres11
         Parameters:
           max_connections: '400' `